# Messagebox datatype C#

Tags: c#

I've created a function for a messagebox but don't know its datatype.Here's my code:

```
public ? ConfirmationMessageBoxTemplate(string Confirmation)
    {
        MetroMessageBox.Show(new frmMainWindow(), Confirmation, "Notice", System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon.Question);

return DialogResult;
    }
```

I have to call that function

```
if (ConfirmationMessageBoxTemplate.OK?)
                {
                    //run code
                }
```

Comment: Where is the method `MetroMessageBox.Show`?

Comment: You're returning `DialogResult`, so the type is `DialogResult`. Also, the first method doesn't compile because you can't simply return `DialogResult`, you need to return one of its members.

Answer (score 2):

[`MetroMessageBox.Show`](https://github.com/dennismagno/metroframework-modern-ui/blob/master/MetroFramework/MessageBox/MetroMessageBox.cs) returns a [`DialogResult`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.dialogresult(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
public DialogResult ConfirmationMessageBoxTemplate(string Confirmation)
{
    return MetroMessageBox.Show(new frmMainWindow(), Confirmation, "Notice", System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon.Question);
}
```

---

```
DialogResult result = ConfirmationMessageBoxTemplate("Hello World");
if (result == DialogResult.OK )
    MessageBox.Show ("User clicked OK button");
else if (result == DialogResult.Cancel)
    MessageBox.Show ("User clicked Cancel button");
```

Comment: Thanks i forgot to call System.Windows.Forms; thats why it gives me an error.